# SOLANA: How to display my candy machine NFT's on metaplex's storefront?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, solana-cli, candy-machine

I minted 30 tokens with candy machine's cli, following the [metaplex's github boilerplate project](https://%20https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/me)

Uploaded, verified, minted and signed all the NFT's. I can see them on my phantom wallet and it created a cache file on the main directory with the candy machine ID. Now I want to know is theirs a way to call my candy machine on the metaplex storefront so I can sell the minted nfts on there.

I think I did it once but now i can't replicate it. I might have been dreaming ...
Any good tutorials on trying to do what I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo it works again!!

I *think* i know why it wasn't working in the first place.

An account address can create many candy machines and when initializing Metaplex's storefront it tries to retrieve all those candy machine instances.

That's why it takes one attribute on the .env file , it gets all the CM's from that one address

[image]

After checking Metaplex discord and various forums it seems as Solana's network is the problem. in short the network is slow and unable to function at scale. As of now (March 30, 2022)

My solution is to only use one address per candy machine instance and maybe that'll help the load

Comment: Mainnet had issues yesterday, for the first time in a while. TPS is back to normal now, you can try again.

Comment: Pretty sure the docs recommend using a different RPC for candy machine as the mainnet isn't designed for it.